# CentOS and vim sourcing vimrc file

Tags: vim

I'm using CentOS, which appears to have vim installed by default. I located the vimrc file in the /etc directory. However, I added `syntax on` and `set number` in the vimrc file and then started vim and created a hello world C program. Neither line had any effect. But when I type `:syntax on` or `:set number` from the command prompt, they work. Thus, it seems the default install somehow can't find the vimrc file (?), since it doesn't appear to use it. When I type at linux prompt: `~/.vimrc` it says "No such file or directory."

Any idea how I specify the location for vim to find vimrc file?

Edit: when I type :version I see,

```
system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/share/vim"
```

But, from linux prompt, when I type echo $VIM nothing is returned. If I export VIM = /etc, still no effect when starting vim. When I echo $HOME I see `/Users/<username>`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just copy the `vimrc` file to your home directory.
The `vimrc` should be as hide... You know **.vimrc**

Comment: cp /ect/vimrc /home/<username>/.vimrc

Comment: Hmm, couldn't get it work. I tried cp /etc/vimrc  /home/<username>/.vimrc, and I can see the file there, but starting vim still shows default settings. Also, tried cp /etc/vimrc  /home/.vimrc, same results. See edit to original question above.

Comment: If I type: `cp /etc/vimrc /Users/<username>/.vimrc` the system responds: `cp: cannot create regular file '/Users/<username>/.vimrc: No such file or directory`

Comment: This is my .vimrc file, It contains:

Comment: set number
set tabstop=2
set ai
syntax on

Comment: Yes, I must have errored in my original copy. But your cp/etc/vimrc /home/<username>/.vimrc works fine now. Thanks so much.

Answer (score 6):

I would normally expect this to reside in your home directory. Note that typing:

```
:version
```

Will tell you where Vim expects to find stuff.

e.g.

```
  system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
  system gvimrc file: "$VIM/gvimrc"
    user gvimrc file: "$HOME/.gvimrc"
    system menu file: "$VIMRUNTIME/menu.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
```